# SSE intrinsics - comparison if/else optimization

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I have been trying to optimize some code which handles raw pixel data. Currently the C++ implementation of the code is too slow, so I've been trying to make some grounds using SSE intrinsics (SSE/2/3 not using 4) with MSVC 2008. Considering it's my first time digging in this low, I've made some good progress.

Unfortunately, I've come to a particular piece of code which has me stuck:

```
//Begin bad/suboptimal SSE code
__m128i vnMask  = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0001);
__m128i vn1     = _mm_and_si128(vnFloors, vnMask);

for(int m=0; m < PBS_SSE_PIXELS_PROCESS_AT_ONCE; m++)
{
    bool bIsEvenFloor   = vn1.m128i_u16[m]==0;

    vnPxChroma.m128i_u16[m] = 
        m%2==0 
            ?
        (bIsEvenFloor ? vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m] : vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m])
            :
        (bIsEvenFloor ? vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m] : vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m]);
}
```

Currently, I'm **defaulting to using a C++ implementation** for this section because I can't quite get my head around how this can be optimized using SSE - I find the SSE intrinsics for comparisons to be a bit tricky.

Any suggestions/tips would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The equivalent C++ code which handles a single pixel at a time would be:

```
short pxCl=0, pxFl=0;
short uv=0; // chroma component of pixel
short y=0;  // luma component of pixel

for(int i = 0; i < end-of-line, ++i)
{
    //Initialize pxCl, and pxFL
    //...

    bool bIsEvenI       = (i%2)==0;
    bool bIsEvenFloor   = (m_pnDistancesFloor[i] % 2)==0;

    uv = bIsEvenI ==0 
        ?
    (bIsEvenFloor ? pxCl : pxFl)
        :
    (bIsEvenFloor ? pxFl : pxCl);

    //Merge the Y/UV of the pixel;
    //...
}
```

Basically, I'm doing a nonlinear edge stretch from 4:3 to 16:9.

Comment: SSE intrinsics are hard to read. Would you mind adding some comments / equivalent C++ code block to explain this section?

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: I'm somewhat perplexed by this snippet (cryptic identifiers and no context), but why don't you replace comparison with multiplication and addition?

Comment: @ZeroDefect could you post your declaration of vnFloors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I don't know what this code is doing, however I do know you are asking how to optimise out the ternery operators and get this portion of code operating only in SSE. As a first step, I would recommend trying an approach using integer flags and multiplication to avoid a conditional operator. For instance:

This section

```
for(int m=0; m < PBS_SSE_PIXELS_PROCESS_AT_ONCE; m++)
{
    bool bIsEvenFloor   = vn1.m128i_u16[m]==0;      

    vnPxChroma.m128i_u16[m] = m%2==0 ?  
      (bIsEvenFloor ? vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m] : vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m])  : 
      (bIsEvenFloor ? vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m] : vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m]); 
}
```

Is syntactically equivalent to this

```
// DISCLAIMER: Untested both in compilation and execution

// Process all m%2=0 in steps of 2
for(int m=0; m < PBS_SSE_PIXELS_PROCESS_AT_ONCE; m+=2)
{
    // This line could surely pack muliple u16s into one SSE2 register
    uint16 iIsOddFloor = vn1.m128i_u16[m] & 0x1 // If u16[m] == 0, result is 0
    uint16 iIsEvenFloor = iIsOddFloor ^ 0x1 // Flip 1 to 0, 0 to 1

    // This line could surely perform an SSE2 multiply across multiple registers
    vnPxChroma.m128i_u16[m] = iIsEvenFloor * vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m] + 
                              iIsOddFloor * vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m]
}

// Process all m%2!=0 in steps of 2
for(int m=1; m < PBS_SSE_PIXELS_PROCESS_AT_ONCE; m+=2)
{
    uint16 iIsOddFloor = vn1.m128i_u16[m] & 0x1 // If u16[m] == 0, result is 0
    uint16 iIsEvenFloor = iIsOddFloor ^ 0x1 // Flip 1 to 0, 0 to 1

    vnPxChroma.m128i_u16[m] = iIsEvenFloor * vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m] + 
                              iIsOddFloor * vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m]
}
```

Basically by splitting into two loops you lose the performance enhancement of serial memory access but drop a modulo operation and two conditional operators.

Now you say, you notice there are two boolean operators per loop as well as the multiplies *which I might add are not SSE intrinsic implementations*. What is stored in your vn1.m123i_u16[] array? Is it only zeros and ones? 
If so you don't need this part and can do away with it. If not, can you normalize your data in this array to only have zeros and ones? If the vn1.m123i_u16 array only contains ones and zeros then this code becomes

```
uint16 iIsOddFloor  = vn1.m128i_u16[m]
uint16 iIsEvenFloor = iIsOddFloor ^ 0x1 // Flip 1 to 0, 0 to 1
```

You will also notice I'm not using SSE multiplies to perform the `isEvenFloor * vnPx... part` nor to store the `iIsEvenFloor` and `iIsOddFloor` registers. Im sorry I can't remember the SSE intrinsics for u16 multiply/register off the top, but nevertheless I hope this approach is helpful. Some optimisations you should look in to:

```
// This line could surely pack muliple u16s into one SSE2 register
uint16 iIsOddFloor = vn1.m128i_u16[m] & 0x1 // If u16[m] == 0, result is 0
uint16 iIsEvenFloor = iIsOddFloor ^ 0x1 // Flip 1 to 0, 0 to 1

// This line could surely perform an SSE2 multiply across multiple registers
vnPxChroma.m128i_u16[m] = iIsEvenFloor * vnPxCeilChroma.m128i_u16[m] + 
                          iIsOddFloor * vnPxFloorChroma.m128i_u16[m]
```

In this section of code you've posted, and my modification, we are still not making full use of the SSE1/2/3 intrinsics but it might provide some points on how that could be done (how to vectorize the code).

Finally I would say to test everything. Run the above code unaltered and profile it before making changes and profiling again. The actual performance numbers may surprise you!

---

**Update 1**:

I've been through the [Intel SIMD Intrinsics documentation](http://cache-www.intel.com/cd/00/00/34/76/347603_347603.pdf) to pick out relevant intrinsics which could be of use for this. Specifically take a look at bitwise XOR, AND and MULT/ADD

> **__m128 Data Types**
>     The __m128i data type can hold sixteen 8-bit, eight 16-bit, four 32-bit, or two 64-bit integer values.
>
> **__m128i _mm_add_epi16(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>     Add the 8 signed or unsigned 16 bit integers in a to the 8 signed or unsigned 16-bit integers in b
>
> **__m128i _mm_mulhi_epu16(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>     Multiplies the 8 unsigned 16-bit integers from a by the 8-unsigned 16-bit integers from b. 
>     Packs the upper 16-bits of the 8-unsigned 32-bit results
>
> R0=hiword(a0 * b0)
>     R1=hiword(a1 * b1)
>     R2=hiword(a2 * b2)
>     R3=hiword(a3 * b3)
>     ..
>     R7=hiword(a7 * b7)
>
> **__m128i _mm_mullo_epi16(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>     Multiplies the 8 signed or unsigned 16-bit integers from a by the 8-signed or unsigned 16-bit integers from b. 
>     Packs the upper 16-bits of the 8-signed or unsigned 32-bit results
>
> R0=loword(a0 * b0)
>     R1=loword(a1 * b1)
>     R2=loword(a2 * b2)
>     R3=loword(a3 * b3)
>     ..
>     R7=loword(a7 * b7)
>
> **__m128i _mm_and_si128(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>     Perform a bitwise AND of the 128-bit value in m1 with the 128-bit value in m2.
>
> **__m128i _mm_andnot_si128(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>     Computes the bitwise AND of the 128-bit value in b and the bitwise NOT of the 128-
>   bit value in a.
>
> **__m128i _mm_xor_si128(__m128i a, __m128i b)**
>      Perform a bitwise XOR of the 128-bit value in m1 with the 128-bit value in m2.
>
> ALSO from your code example for reference
>
> uint16 u1 = u2 = u3 ... = u15 = 0x1
>     __m128i vnMask  = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0001); // Sets the 8 signed 16-bit integer values.
>
> uint16 vn1[i] = vnFloors[i] & 0x1
>     __m128i vn1     = _mm_and_si128(vnFloors, vnMask); // Computes the bitwise AND of the 128-bit value in a and the 128-bit value in b.

Comment: Is it possible to use bitwise AND instead of multiplication ?

Comment: Thanks, I have already broken down the C++ implementation into two (2) separate for loops as you suggested.

I hadn't considered using multiplication/add for doing the comparison. The part I'm keen on is to combine the two for loops into one (1) set of instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew your suggestions lead me down the path to a near-optimal solution.

Using a combination of a truth table and karnaugh map, I discovered that the code

```
 uv = bIsEvenI ==0 
    ?
(bIsEvenFloor ? pxCl : pxFl)
    :
(bIsEvenFloor ? pxFl : pxCl);
```

boiled down to being a !xor (not xor) function. From then on, I was able to use SSE vectorization to optimize the solution:

```
//Use the mask with bit AND to check if even/odd
__m128i vnMask              = _mm_set1_epi16(0x0001);

//Set the bit to '1' if EVEN, else '0'
__m128i vnFloorsEven        = _mm_andnot_si128(vnFloors, vnMask);
__m128i vnMEven             = _mm_set_epi16
    (
        0,  //m==7
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1,
        0,  //m==1
        1   //m==0
    );


// Bit XOR the 'floor' values and 'm'
__m128i vnFloorsXorM        = _mm_xor_si128(vnFloorsEven, vnMEven);

// Now perform our bit NOT
__m128i vnNotFloorsXorM     = _mm_andnot_si128(vnFloorsXorM, vnMask);

// This is the C++ ternary replacement - using multipilaction
__m128i vnA                 = _mm_mullo_epi16(vnNotFloorsXorM, vnPxFloorChroma);
__m128i vnB                 = _mm_mullo_epi16(vnFloorsXorM, vnPxCeilChroma);

// Set our pixels - voila!
vnPxChroma                  = _mm_add_epi16(vnA, vnB);
```

Thanks for all the help...

Comment: Wow! Well done and good work for posting the solution!! Out of interest, what is the performance like of the SSE version vs. vanilla C++ code? `truth table and karnaugh map` Like it. I remember doing those for GCSE electronics!

Comment: Thank you. The SSE implementation runs in less than half the time. Originally (before posting this post), I took a look at the assembled C++ implementation in hopes that it would share some suggestions. Unfortunately, the C++ implementation is severely hampered by all the branching (and cache misses) - it does not make the most of the !xor pattern. And yes, Karnaugh maps are the bomb.

Comment: Great! Although c you are using u16 there is  a maximum theoretical speed improvement of 8x to capture. Easier said than done as you've probably found out!